# update panel and modal windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have my mainpage.aspx and then my mainDetails.ascx

```js
/*As well as this javascript:*/
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#modal-close").click(function() {
    $("#modal-content, #modal-background, #modal-close").toggleClass("active");
  });
  $("#keywordSelection").click(function() {
    alert('hit');
  });
});
/*mainDetails.ascx is an `asp:UpdatePanel` this contains the following javascript:*/
function jsModal() {
  $("#keywordSearch").click(function() {
    //alert('hi');
    $("#modal-content, #modal-background, #modal-close").toggleClass("active");
    //$("#modal-content").$("divTestVal").append.html

    var html = $("#modal-content").next("#divTestVal").html();
    alert(html);
  });
}
```

```html
<!-- mainpage.aspx is a web form that contains the following:-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="modal-background"></div>
<div id="modal-content">
  <input type="button" id="modal-close" value="Close Modal Window" />
  <br />
  <div id="divTestVal">
    [Append Values Here!]
  </div>
  <br />
  <input type="button" id="keywordSelection" value="Selector!" />
</div>
```

What I need is a way to populate and read the values from the modal.  Right now the html variable is returning `null`.

How do a get the `[Append Values Here!]` value from the modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way of doing it.

in the mainDetail.ascx javascript I added the following:

```
        $('#modal-content div').each(function (index) {
            alert($(this).text());
            $(this).html("updated text now");
        });
```

Not only does this loop through each div in the modal window on the mainpage.aspx, but it also updates the text values in the div.