# calling javascript located in updatepanel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Following up on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815905/update-panel-and-modal-windows)

I have a mainpage.aspx and a maindetail.ascx
Each have javascript functions.  My question is how can I can call a javascript function that resides on maindetail.ascx from a javascript function on mainpage.aspx?

**maindetail.ascx:**

```
    function populateDropDowns() {
        alert('got here!');
    }
```

**mainpage.aspx:**

```
        $("#keywordSelection").click(function () {
            populateDropDowns();
        });
```

Right now I'm getting an error that states:

> The value of the property 'populateDropDowns' is null or undefined,
>   not a Function object

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the control instanace name OR control new object name that generated in mainpage.aspx

for example **keywordSelection.ClientID**
hope this code will work for you

```
        $('#<%= keywordSelection.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            populateDropDowns();
        });
```

**if this help plzmark as answer thanks**